# echo php output to html / javascript as variables

Tags: php, html

I have a segment of html where I am plotting a single lat/lon coordinate as such:

```
var marker = L.marker([100,-70]);
marker.addTo(map)
```

I would like to dynamically plot coordinates based on a locally-placed text file with contents as such:

```
file.txt:
1,100.0,-77.1
2,100.0,-77.2
3,100.0,-77.3
```

I can open the text file with php:

```
readfile.php:
<?php
$myfile = fopen("file.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
echo fread($myfile,filesize("file.txt"));
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

which will echo the contents of file.txt. However, now I would like to pass not only the contents of the lat/lon of the php output, but also be able to loop through the contents to be able to plot X number of markers based on the length of file.txt

What is the easiest way to communicate / pass the read contents of the textfile via php?